# How to Log in F# in a functional way using NLog

Tags: logging, f#, nlog

I have been looking at logging options and settled on NLog and logging to a database

I am fairly new to functional programming and have come from a background in C# OOP.

How would I implement logging in a functional way in F#?
Do I

- Create the logger at the top level and just pass it in to every function as I go
- Access the logger through a static method as needed ( obviously there would be some overhead to instantiating a logger each time - but maybe that's not a big deal )
- Something else?

I want to avoid using a commercial logging option just because my projects are quite small.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Access the logger through a static method

This approach is fine for experimental applications, but generally speaking it is the instance of [Service Locator](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) which is commonly considered as antipattern.

More solid alternative is dependency injection (DI). Since F# is hybrid language, you can use OOP concepts and apply the DI pattern in common way for OOP. However if you want to use the functional style, there is no single common functional pattern for DI in F#.

> Create the logger at the top level and just pass it in to every function

This is just the most straightforward way of using DI in functional code. This approach may work fine for small applications, however if along with logging you have other cross-cutting concerns (such as configuration), you may end up with explosion of arguments, which clutters up the code.
There are different approaches how to address this problem. I have settled with approach described [here](https://bartoszsypytkowski.com/dealing-with-complex-dependency-injection-in-f/#managing-dependencies-beyond-partial-application).

You can apply this approach in a following way.

Your function with business logic may look like this:

```
let doSomething env = 
    let logger = getLogger env
    logger.Debug("Do something")
    // Do something
```

It means that `logger` reference is provided via `env` parameter and accessed via the function `getLogger`.

This code should reference the common logging module, which may look like this:

```
[<Interface>]
type ILoggerProvider =
    abstract Logger: ILogger

let getLogger (env: #ILoggerProvider) = env.Logger
```

Notice that type of `env` parameter of `doSomething` is automatically inferred as `#ILoggerProvider` (that is inherits `ILoggerProvider`).

Imaging that later in the same business logic we need to access the configuration (along with logging). In this case we do not need new parameter, but access the configuration from the same `env` parameter in similar way: `let configuration = getConfiguration env`, provided that common module for configuration is created as well:

```
[<Interface>]
type IConfigurationProvider =
    abstract Configuration: IConfiguration

let getConfiguration (env: #IConfigurationProvider) = env.Configuration
```

In this case type of `env` parameter of `doSomething` is automatically re-inferred to
`'a (requires 'a :> ILoggerProvider and 'a :> IConfigurationProvider)`
which means that it should inherit both `ILoggerProvider` and `IConfigurationProvider`.

On application level you need to create the instance of environment and pass it to business logic in order to provide the access to logging and configuration (and possibly other services). You can do it in a following way:

```
[<Interface>] 
type IEnvironment = 
    inherit ILoggerProvider 
    inherit IConfigurationProvider
    
let createEnvironment (logger, configuration) = 
    { new IEnvironment with
        member self.Logger = logger 
        member self.Configuration = configuration }

let createLogger () = // create logger...
    
let createConfiguration () = // create configuration...

let logger = createLogger ()
let configuration = createConfiguration ()
let env = createEnvironment (logger, configuration)

// Call business logic
doSomething env
```

Notice, that it is easy to extend this code with new cross-cutting concerns, since each of business logic functions is aware only of used services (such as logging, configuration) and knows nothing about `IEnvironment` interface and all its content.

You can find the full version of my example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/blLSC8#).

More comprehensive overview of DI approaches in F# you may find [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/dependencies/).

Answer (score 1):

As logging is inherently impure there isn't a particularly clean way to do logging that I'm aware of. You have basically identified the two solutions in your question. Which one you use depends on what the logs are being used for.

For logging to external services I would consider creating an `AppContext` type which is home to app and user settings as well as providing functions or methods for logging to e.g. a database. This type should be added an extra parameter in your functions or an additional field in your types depending on what makes the most sense.

For your lowest-level functions rather than changing them all to accept an additional parameter you should consider altering the return type to include the information you want to log and leaving the act of logging to higher level parts of your program.

For logging to a console, rolling buffer, or other temporary location I think it is fine to create a `module` which is equivalent to a C# static class and just provide globally accessible logging functions.